# Exclude maven dependency for tests

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a dependency that is needed for a compilation and runtime but I want to exclude it when running tests. Is this possible? Maybe, by setting up a profile? But how do I deactivate it only for `test` lifecycle phase?

Comment: That sounds wrong in my mind? You need it for compiling and runtime but not for Testing? What are you testing?

Comment: @khmarbaise I know it might sound strange. The problem is that I need to use one logback implementation version for compilation and runtime, but another one for tests (which comes as a transitive dependency from embedded-glassfish-all with `test scope`).

Comment: If you have embedded glassfish your tests whould not tests things like this. This sounds like integration tests.

Comment: Yep, we're doing some integration testing. But this doesn't really matter. I'm trying to find out if there is a way to exclude a dependency during certain phase.

Comment: What about one profile for each logback implementation ?

Comment: @gontard I actually mentioned `profiles` in my question. I just can't figure out how to activate/deactivate a profile for some specific phase in one run. I'm afraid it's hardly possible.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You could (re)configure the classpath during the test phase thanks to the [maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html). You can add classpath elements or exclude dependencies.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/additional/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
            <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/additional/jar</additionalClasspathElement>
          </additionalClasspathElements>
          <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            <classpathDependencyExclude>org.apache.commons:commons-email</classpathDependencyExclude>
          </classpathDependencyExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

[As noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053316/exclude-maven-dependency-for-tests/12068045#comment16347219_12068045) by @jFrenetic you could do the same with [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html).

Comment: This is actually a very good soultion! Considering that unit and integration tests are executed by different plugins (`surefire` and `failsafe`), it's very convenient to manage classpath using plugin-specific configuration.

Comment: Heads'up.  This does not play well with IntellJ Idea Test Runner.  The `maven-surefire-plugin ` Exclude `classpathDependencyExclude ` configuration seems to be ignored.  Meaning your only workaround on IntellJ Idea is to use the Terminal to run your test or the Maven Project tool window. [See open ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122783) .  That said this works with Eclipse.

Comment: This is now working in 2019.3 Intellij.  Refer https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122783 .

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Eclipse `Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)` - it does work when running tests from the Maven command line.