# How to exclude a dependency for a specific scope only?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have two dependencies in my pom called A and B. Both A and B have a transitive dependency on an artifact C (cassandra-all). A and B use difference versions of C. Dependency A is the artifact *astyanax*.

 
I want to keep the **Version** of C that comes with B. I accomplished by adding an exclusion in A (Astyanax) for C.

Unfortunately, I want the scope of B to be 'test'. This means that with the exclusion in A, C will not be included outside of the test scope.

How can I resolve this?  Can an exclusion be for a specific scope only?  Alternatively, can I specify which version to use for a transitive dependency?

---

**Example:** 
Here is what my pom looks like:

**Artifact A (astyanax) with exclusion of dependency on Artifact C (called cassandra-all)**

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.astyanax</groupId>
        <artifactId>astyanax</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>  
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

So concretely: how can I include cassandra-all when I run code outside of the test scope and still keep the scope of cassandraunit test only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude maven dependency for tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053316/exclude-maven-dependency-for-tests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I apologize if my question wasn't as clear as it could have been.  The way I resolved this wasn't hard at all:

- I added a separate dependency for C in my pom
- I kept the exclusion of C in A

Concretely here, I just added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

and also the following dependency that was missing at runtime otherwise.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood everything, but, in any case, you should be able to achieve this with profiles.

In your pom, create a profile A in which you add your dependency A with exclusion of B and a profile B in which you'll have a dependency with exclusion of A.

On runtime, depending on which of the profile you have selected you'll include one or the other.

HIH

Answer (score 1):

> So concretely: how can I include cassandra-all when I run code outside of the test scope and still keep the scope of cassandraunit test only?

[Use Maven POM to configure surefire-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12068045/1287376) and [change your classpath](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html).

If what you want is only that the `cassandra-all` dependency be removed from the classpath while running your tests, then the following POM snippet would make the tricky:

```xml
<build>
  <!-- ... -->

  <plugins>
    <!-- ... -->

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <classpathDependencyExcludes>
          <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all
          </classpathDependencyExcludes>
        </classpathDependencyExcludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```