# How do I include dependencies only in my war?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, war

I would like to include (maven) dependencies in my war while making sure that they are **not** in the runtime or test scope.

The problem is the following:

1. There a number of jars (let's say jar A, B, and C) that I need in my war. This is because of the use of CDI.
2. I have a number of integration tests that use the war produced by the project. These integration tests are [arquillian](http://arquillian.org) based tests.
3. However, I have other tests that are *not* integration tests that will be adversely affected by the inclusion of jars A, B and C on the class path.

Comment: See you main options [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). There does not seem to be one that does what you want.

Comment: there is no option to do what you want, it doesn't make any sense to not want something in `test` scope anyway. maybe if you posted what you are actually trying to achieve maybe someone might be able to offer a solution.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Thank you! Could you submit it as answer so I can mark it as such? As to whether or not it's makes sense, please tell me how I can otherwise create a war for an arquillian test without the dependencies adversely affecting other tests?

Comment: @Marco, have you taken a look at using Shrinkwrap to dynamically create test archives?

Comment: @Perception Yes, I'm well acquainted with Shrinkwrap. It's a great tool -- and also doesn't fit my use case.

Comment: Explain how a dependency would adversely affect other tests? Please edit your question with the response, don't leave it as another comment so everyone will read it without having to dig through the comments section.

Comment: @Marco - Shrinkwrap allows you to dynamically build a WAR containing pretty much anything you want. It can pull Maven dependencies or standalone resources in your classpath. If that doesn't fit your requirement then you might want to expand on what those requirements are.

Comment: @Marco - I see you edited your question to include more detail, +1. The canonical way to handle situations like this in Arquillian is to extend those specific test cases that require a specialized deployment from a common superclass that defines the deployable archive. All other classes would define their deployable as they see fit. This is the workaround that has been proposed while the implementation of ArquillianSuites proceeds.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the `dependency:copy-dependencies` goal to copy particular dependencies somewhere, then modify the configuration of the war plugin to pull in files from this temporary location at assembly time? I've done something like this in the past when dealing with WARs in OSGi containers. If you think this might work for you, I can post a more complete answer with details.

Comment: @PeterMularien Good suggestion, I hadn't considered that yet. Unfortunate the [copy-dependencies page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) mentions that it "Requires dependency resolution of artifacts in scope: test" -- and that's exactly my problem: they can't be in the test scope.

Comment: @Marco, right, that's the default behavior, but you can use the `includeScope` or `excludeScope` configuration options to narrow the scope of the dependencies copied.

Comment: @PeterMularien .. but isn't `excludeScope` a parameter for `copy-dependencies`? In other words, `excludeScope` doesn't modify the scope of the actual dependency on the classpath.

Comment: @Marco - sorry, perhaps I read the question wrong. It sounds like what you're looking for is a scope that is part of compile, but not test. Have you tried the answer suggested in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053316/exclude-maven-dependency-for-tests

Comment: @Marco, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good options**:

Ah HA! It's possible to exclude certain dependencies from the test phase by using the surefire-plugin. That's described in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12068045/376390).

This way I can create my war and not have the dependencies in the test scope (thanks [Peter Mularien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159538/peter-mularien))!

**Bad options**:

It looks like the maven assembly plugin requires you to have any `include` dependencies also available in a dependency scope. Since `test` is the smallest scope, it's impossible to include a dependency in your war without having it also be available on the test scope of the project.

The maven war plugin does not allow you to include (or exclude) dependencies.

Another other option is to create a second "distribution" module that includes the needed dependencies in it's pom. However, that means that the arquillian test is then referencing the previous build's war -- which is also not ideal.

Yet another option is to use Shrinkwrap to create a jar with tests and fork the JVM to run the "test" jar -- I've done this before when I needed to test my code with multiple ORM's (otherwise, having OpenJPA in your path conflicts with having Hibernate in your path, for example). But that disconnects your tests from your test framework (JUnit, TestNG, etc.) and makes the tests hard to debug.

Answer (score 4):

`war` is not a dependency scope. Valid scopes are `provided`, `compile`, `runtime`, `test`, `system`. You can select only one of those, they are the only options and none of them exclude from the `test` scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have  attribute with several options: runtime, test, compile, etc.

For example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

More you can read [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Comment: Unfortunately, *runtime* scope means that the dependency is also available in *test* scope. Please reread the question!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the scope in the dependencies section like below. It can be mentioned as test, compile or runtime.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.integration.adapter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>            
    </dependency>
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks, KJ

Comment: As I mention above, *runtime* scope means that the dependency is also available in *test* scope, which is precisely what I do not want.