# Exclude maven dependency for one specific unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit

I'd like to remove a dependency for a unit test. I found how to do it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053316/exclude-maven-dependency-for-tests).

But I'd like to remove a dependency for only one specific test, not for all my tests. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't think so, cause dependencies are for the maven module. If you need this for only a single test you might need to move this test to a separate maven module. But it sounds like integration tests and not like a unit test. May be you can elaborate a little bit more or post your pom file?

Comment: It's true that it is more an integration test, it is to test the behavior of my application when a specific dependency is missing.

Comment: Than you should separate out that test into a separate maven module.

Comment: Then you need to create one module for each integration test?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by using one Surefire execution.

You will have to define two executions of the Surefire plugin: one containing the full Classpath for most of the tests, and one containing the specialized Classpath for the single test that requires it.

Follow the Surefire plugin's documentation: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

You'll have to create two executions, and bind them both to the `test` phase. Use the following example as a skeleton (you'll have to adjust the `include` and `exclude` patterns, as well as the excluded Classpath artifact):

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>full-cp</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>MyFancyTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>special-cp</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>MyFancyTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                        <classpathDependencyExcludes>excluded-artifact</classpathDependencyExcludes>
                    </classpathDependencyExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Surefire plugin is not intended for integration tests. Integration test should be run by the maven-failsafe-plugin instead.

Comment: Thx a lot. While khmarbaise is right, Isaac answers my question nevertheless. I will look into maven-failsafe-plugin. But the documentation looks terrible :p