# Removing maven dependancies of child pom from parent pom

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a parent pom A with children pom B, C and D.  In the B, C and D, I have dependencies with the same type.

ie 
Parent Pom

```
    <artifactID>blah</artifactID>
    <modules>
        <module>B</module>
        <module>C</module>
        <module>D</module>
    </modules>
```

child Pom

```
    <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              .
              .
              <scope>test</scope>
              <type>test-jar</type>
          </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

So far I have tried editing the plugin-surefire and that did not work when trying to exclude the test scope for the child poms.

My question is if there is a way to add a profile to the parent pom to exclude all dependencies with the type test-jar for all child poms.
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do it without specifying every one?

Comment: Is it an option to put a profile in the child pom that uses the test-jars and the parent pom not use this profile?

Comment: Look at this---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053316/exclude-maven-dependency-for-tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to update paths in `test` scope, you can hook the `maven-surfire-plugin` which is actually responsible of building test classpath and exclude undesired dependencies or add new ones. So, if you want this restriction *to be applied per module* you can add below entry to child poms, e.g. for **B**:

```
<project>
  ...
  <artifactId>B</artifactId>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            <classpathDependencyExclude>${undesired-dependency-groupId}:${undesired-dependency-artifactId}</classpathDependencyExclude>
          </classpathDependencyExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Or if you want this restriction *to be inherited by all child modules*, do define in parent pom as profile based plugin:

```
<project>
  ...
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <module>B</module>
  <module>C</module>
  <module>D</module>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>custom-test-goal</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
              <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                <classpathDependencyExclude>${undesired-dependency-groupId}:${undesired-dependency-artifactId}</classpathDependencyExclude>
              </classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Hi So I would have to do this for each module?  Is there a way to do this just in the parent or encapsulate it in a profile?

Comment: You can move this declaration into parent pom then wrap the `<plugin>` declaration inside `<pluginManagement>` tag. Then simply inside child poms call that `<plugin>`:

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>

Or use profile based activation plugin. I will update the answer.

Comment: Alright, So I have tried that but maven is still trying to download the dependency, which is causing the error.  I believe my problem is different then I first assumed. Thanks

Comment: At least you can upvote the answer if it helped figuring out half of the way :)